# Getting a blank screen when deploying a react app made from a template on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-hosting

I know there are a lot of similar questions on here, but none of the solutions provided for those worked for me. This is my first time building an app, so I am missing a lot of basic knowledge. I am trying to deploy a React App to Firebase Hosting (built off the Material Kit 2 React template made by Creative Tim, which I believe is a modified create-react-app using custom material-ui components).

Problem:

When I deploy my app, the deployment runs successfully but the page at my domain is blank. I have tried running the firebase init by selecting both Y and N for the "rewrite urls to index.html" option, which caused the error for many others here. In both cases, I still get errors.

Here is the console error with Y:

```
2.829b5606.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.744b60c8.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

And here is the console error with N (which is suspect is the right choice):

```
2.d7abbed5.chunk.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.a89f12e7.chunk.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I am still not sure which of these options is correct but I also don't think this is the core source of the error. I tried creating a standard create-react-app and it deployed no problem. I also did not forget to run npm run build before deploying.

Here is the code from some of my files (I believe the issue may have to do with my routing or the jsconfig.json [which I do not understand at all]):

firebase.json w/ N for index.html rewrite option

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

firebase.json w/ Y for index.html rewrite option

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

// react-router components
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// @mui material components
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";

// Material Kit 2 PRO React themes
import theme from "assets/theme";
import Home from "pages/Home";

// Material Kit 2 PRO React routes
import routes from "routes";

export default function App() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  // Setting page scroll to 0 when changing the route
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }, [pathname]);

  const getRoutes = (allRoutes) =>
    allRoutes.map((route) => {
      if (route.collapse) {
        return getRoutes(route.collapse);
      }

      if (route.route) {
        return <Route exact path={route.route} element={route.component} key={route.key} />;
      }

      return null;
    });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Routes>
        {getRoutes(routes)}
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
      </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

jsconfig.json (which sits outside the src folder in the main directory)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "edyou-website",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": "EDYou LLC",
  "license": "See license in https://www.edyou.org/license",
  "description": "React company website for EDYou LLC",
  "homepage": "https://www.edyou.org/home",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-kit-pro-react/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-kit-pro-react.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14 || 15 || 16",
    "npm": ">=6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "11.4.0",
    "@emotion/react": "11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.2.0",
    "@mui/material": "5.2.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "5.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.1.10",
    "chroma-js": "2.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.9",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.0.4",
    "react-countup": "6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-flatpickr": "3.10.7",
    "react-router-dom": "6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "15.4.5",
    "rellax": "1.12.1",
    "swiper": "7.3.4",
    "typed.js": "2.0.12",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you deploying the app? The solution generally depends on the answer to this question. Effectively you need to properly configure for the server environment. See the [CRA deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) if there's a relevant section matching where you are deploying your app to. The gist is that the server needs redirect page requests to the root index.html file so your React app loads and can handle routing & navigation internally.

Comment: I am deploying to firebase hosting. I more or less followed these instructions (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-react-project-on-firebase/) and tried those in similar YouTube videos after it didn't work.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase

Comment: Okay. I tried adding that snippet to the firebase.json file where I select Y (per the instructions in that article), but I am still getting blank page with the same console error of unexpected syntax. The template I am using is heavily modified and looks nothing like the create-react-app standard file. I don't even see a service-worker.js file.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` often means you're receiving an HTML page (often a 404 or other error page)  instead of whatever data or script you were expecting.  Try loading those filepaths directly in the browser and see what you get

Comment: This is where my lack of basic knowledge may be an issue. Based on your comment I tried typing in some of the url paths I expected to work (that do work in localhost). If this was not correct, could you point me to a resource, so I can follow your advice? Also is selecting yes for single-page app during firebase init for sure correct, even with multi-page react routing? Because I only get a normal 404 error if I don't select yes at that step.